# Should cached data be kept separate from primary tables?

Tags: database, database-design, sql, caching

I have a table in an SQL database for storing information about some business object that looks something like this (details changed so as not to give away what company I work for):

```sql
CREATE TABLE product (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    price MONEY NOT NULL,
    ...  -- Some other stuff
);
```

This data is updated "manually" (with a tool) and rarely changes.

I'm planning to cache the result of an expensive operation that we normally do at runtime in the DB, which maps 1-to-1 with the aforementioned table. The cache should be able to be cleared and rebuilt every few minutes.

My instinct is to keep this autogenerated data in a separate table, with a foreign key linking it to the manually updated table. Something like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE product_is_popular_cache (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES product(id),
    is_popular BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

My question is: Is this just unnecessary complication? I could make it a new column on the original table, but mixing human-generated and machine-generated data smells to me. Perhaps there is a performance benefit. I could imagine that deleting and inserting many rows faster than scanning the `product` table and changing only the relevant rows. Maybe they scale differently.

Comment: Typically a cache lives outside the database to offload workload from the database.

Comment: @JonRaynor In this case, external data is being cached to offload work from the external service.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a requirement that they be separate, so *should* may be too strong a word.

However, there are certain things you can do when you keep it separate. For example, you could index your static table with a 100% fill factor, which will improve performance, without needing to reindex each time the cache is refreshed. You could deploy the cache to a different filegroup on a faster drive. You might want to exclude the cache from backups, or put it on a different schedule. If the table gets very heavy traffic, you could even replicate it to scale out.

Also, if you are following the [principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege), you may want to assign different permissions for updating the static table vs. updating the cache. That would be easier to administer if the data were kept separate.